# Using python and postgressql how do I Insert variable values into a select statement

Tags: python, postgresql

Using python and Postgresql, I have a list of values in a variable which look like this:

```
MLVN
AAOG
TAN
ITX
OMI
OSI

for epic in epics:
    text = epic.text
    print(text)
    instrument=cursor.execute("""SELECT epic FROM instrument_static where ticker IN ='%s'""" % (epic))
    print(instrument)
```

For each value I want to search by it in my database one way of doing this is using the IN operator but not sure how I  address that in the code above. Using the code as it is gives me an error:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "="
LINE 1: ...ELECT epic FROM instrument_static where ticker IN ='<seleniu...
                                                             ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `=` with `IN` statement in `sql`. Instead do this:

```
instrument = cursor.execute("SELECT epic FROM instrument_static where ticker = (?)", (epic))
```

Avoid using `%s`. It can lead to [`sql injection`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Thanks but still getting error: psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "="
LINE 1: SELECT epic FROM instrument_static where ticker IN =(?)

Comment: Sorry the error was actually this psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: SELECT epic FROM instrument_static where ticker IN (?)